# Entity framework running sprocs and native queries performance considerations

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I'm wondering if there's a performance penalty when doing the following vs using plain old ado.net DataReader and DataTable:

```
using(DBEntities dbEntities = new dbEntities)
{
    ObjectResult<tblCustomers> customers =
        dbEntities.ExecuteStoreQuery<tblCustomers>("SELECT name,id FROM tblCustomers");
}
```

I would also like to run sprocs using dbEntity.

I mention this because i'm developing a highly performance sensitive application but would still like to use the entity framework.

furthermore, can anyone point me to recent performance tests of linq to entities compiled queries on .net 4.0?

**EDIT**
If i go with ado.net i plan on inserting the results i get from each row to a .net object manually. So it's entity framework storequery/sproc vs ado.net + manually creating and inserting data to a .net object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course - this is a higher-level approach than plain ADO.NET / SQL.

You send in a SQL query and get back a list of `tblCustomers` objects. Somewhere along the line, a mapping from the database's row/column to the object will happen, and this does take some time.

On the other hand - if you want to do the same thing yourself, you will have to pay a performance penalty, too - or you just use the old-style row/column to do your work (**not** recommended!).

It's the classic "convenience vs. performance" trade-off - what is more important to you? Being able to program with nice C# objects and their properties and be very productive as a programmer - or a few nanoseconds on the SELECT from your database? It's your pick....

Comment: I am of course planning on inserting the results to an object if i go with ado.net, perhaps i wasn't clear enough, i meant a performance penalty for running the query itself and not the time it takes to convert it to an object (truly negligible as you mentioned).

Comment: @dortzur: I don't have any numbers to back this up, but you can pretty much assume that Microsoft will do anything in their powers to make these things as fast as possible - typically, "do it yourself" hardly ever works faster - unless you can exploit some information about the system that a general-purpose approach cannot possibly have.

Comment: @dortzur: under the covers, I'm pretty sure this code also uses an ADO.NET connection and a `DataReader` to grab its data - can't really be much faster than that....

Comment: Since we don't know the performance requirements, the environment or what the OP is actually trying to achieve with the data he's retreiving, your **not** recommended comment assumes a lot. Are you suggesting that classes are always better than just working with the row? I suspect that in most instances you're correct but not necessarily always.